# Problem with GET values from JSON format using Jquery

Tags: jquery, json, jquery-mobile

I trying get some values from remote server, which generate data in JSON format>

```
$("#productSearchpage").live("pageshow", function(event, ui){

            $.getJSON('http://www.akcniceny.cz/php/mapa-slev-data.php?box[left][lat]=50.5&box[left][lng]=14.5&box[right][lat]=51&box[right][lng]=15&group[]=3&typ[]=zbozi&full=televizor', function(data) {
              $('.result').html('<p>' + data.jmeno + '</p>'
                + '<p>' + data.ulice[1] + '</p>');
            });
```

But i have not experience with JSON and so tryied used by tutorial on Jquery site, unfortunately script does not work.

What can   be worng and how to right USE JQUERY and JSON together?

Thanks for any reply.

Comment: When I open that URL in my browser, I get an 500 Internal Server error. Have you made sure the URL is correct?

Comment: The url you are requesting in not rendering any data.. Please check with the url you are pinging, it should render a json output.

Comment: you hava an extra coma at the end of the json string [{},] look @ntiziolis

Comment: And why is none of the answers accepted? Jiří Vávrů, you should click on the tick next to the answer that fixed your problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**The json returned by the server is not valid.**
Basically it returns an array of objects, but after the last object there is an unnecessary comma (which usually indicates that another object is the array).

When constructing the json server side **remove the last comma** before returning the response.

If you don't have access to the server side code you will not be able to use `$.getJSON`. You will need flow these steps:

- Use the `$.ajax` method with config: `dataType: text`
- Use java script string manipulation to remove the trailing comma
- Parse the string as json using `$.parseJSON`

Answer (score 0):

Please, try this:

```
$("#productSearchpage").live("pageshow", function(event, ui){
    $.ajax({
        url: 'http://www.akcniceny.cz/php/mapa-slev-data.php?box[left][lat]=50.5&box[left][lng]=14.5&box[right][lat]=51&box[right][lng]=15&group[]=3&typ[]=zbozi&full=televizor',
        dataType: 'json',
        data: data,
        success: $('.result').html('<p>' + data.jmeno + '</p>'+ '<p>' + data.ulice[1] + '</p>');
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Is this script in the same domain?
If not browsers don't allow cross-domain get / post using xmlhttp request. You might have to use other workarounds. [Here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy) are the details.

Comment: if is not on same domain you can use jsonP, jQuery knows it.

Comment: @Elzo Valugi for this to work the server side needs to support jsonp, since the json returned is already invalid i doubt that the server side supports the jsonp response type yet

Comment: jsonP is just json with a string callback, the server does not need anything special, just to spit some text and send a text/javascript header.